# How to set background color in CCLabelTTF in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently using Cocos2d FrameWork for my Game. I need to change the background color in a CCLabelTTF.I know how to set font color, can someone please tell me how to change background color of the CCLabelTTF object.

```
CCLabelTTF *nameLabel=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[plyName objectAtIndex:i]] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:20];
        nameLabel.position=ccp(100,y1);
        nameLabel.color=ccc3(245, 222, 179);
        [self addChild:nameLabel];
```

This is my sample code for adding Label.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, you can create CCColorLayer or just sprite and set up the exactly content size as it has CCLableTTF

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can not set the background color of a CCLabelTTF.

What you can do is to display a single color CCSprite behind the label, or use [CCLayerColor](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_layer_color.html) in the background with the same width and height of the label.

Comment: CCLabelTTF class is not available in android?