# Cocos2D CCLabelTTF diplays solid rectangle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to implement a debug layer in my iOS application to help getting feedback from testers.

Found [this solution](https://github.com/erikolsson/Cocos2d-Debug-Layer) on GitHub that does exactly what I want: a transparent layer on top of the application, where I can print debug info.

The cocos2d-debug-layer uses `CCLabelTTF` to display the debug messages.

I have successfully inserted this API into my code and it works almost as expected.
The only problem is that some messages appear as a solid rectangle, while some appear correctly.

I have tried to change the `ccLabelTTF`’s color, and it has an effect, but it changes the text and background color also. If I don’t change its color (leave defaults), it prints a white rectangle.

I have found that `ccLabelTTF`’s background [cannot be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928968/how-to-set-background-color-in-cclabelttf-in-cocos2d). I cannot set the background to transparent.

I use the `CocosDebugLayer` like this:

Initializing in `gamescene.m`:

```
+(id) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    seraphinGame *layer = [seraphinGame node];
    [scene addChild: layer];

    //add debug layer
    CocosDebugLayer *debugLayer = [CocosDebugLayer node];
    [scene addChild:debugLayer z:10000];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LogMessage" object:@"Init scene"];

    return scene;
}
```

Sending log messages several places in the same `.m` file:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LogMessage" object:@"Other log message"];
```

The first line is printed right: "Init scene"

But thereafter, it prints solid blocks.

The Label's font is Helvetica which is available by default.
It can not be a problem, because some messages appear right some not.

This is the code for creating `ccLabelTTF`s:

```
-(void)logMessage:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSString *message = [notification object];
    CCLabelTTF *logMsg = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:message fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:12];
    [logMsg setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
    [self addChild:logMsg];
    [logMessages addObject:logMsg];
    [logMsg release];
    [self updateLog];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the label's font simply isn't available and therefore it creates a blank, opaque texture? What font are the labels using? Try changing the fontName parameter to "Arial" or "Courier" for fixed-width.

Comment: Does not duplicate with cocos2d 2.0.